# I want to Add "IF STATEMENT" If the Criteria Exist or Not on FilterMode

Tags: excel, vba

I will like to add an `If` criteria when `Last name` is not found. If it is found then keep filter with criteria.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim PnrName As String
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Fltrrng As Range
    
    Firstrow = Range("B:B").Find("*", After:=Range("I1")).Row
    Lastrow = Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    PnrName = InputBox("Please Enter Last Name")
    
    Set Fltrrng = ActiveSheet.Range("$I$" & Firstrow & ":$I$" & Lastrow)
    
    Fltrrng.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="=" & PnrName & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
    
    '**If **PnrName is found keep filter**
    'Else
    'MsgBox "Last Name does not exist, Please Re-Enter Last Name"
    'End If**
End Sub
```

Comment: You know you do not have to use `AutoFilter` to check if a text is in a particular column or not? A simple `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf()` can tell you that and if the count is `>0` then you can use that in the `AutoFilter`.

Comment: Its Wrong, but I imagen somenthing like below?

Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("$A$" & Firstrow & ":$A$" & Lastrow))
    If Count > 0 Then
    Fltrrng.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="=" & PnrName & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
    Else
    MsgBox ("Last Name " & PnrName & "Does not Exist")
    End If

Comment: No. You are missing the 2nd argument. [WorksheetFunction.CountIf method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif) Try this `Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("$A$" & Firstrow & ":$A$" & Lastrow), PnrName)`

Comment: BTW if `Field:=9` then not sure why are you searching in Col A?

Comment: I saw that error and I fix as well, yes, i was missing 2nd argument just 1 issue, i'm using 
 Criteria1:="=" & PnrName & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
and does not count if word its not compleat

Comment: you do not need `, Operator:=xlAnd`

Comment: @SiddharthRout thank you for you help! I ended using "=" & PnrName & "*" on second argument :D

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me now.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim PnrName As String
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Fltrrng As Range
    Dim Count As Long

    Firstrow = Range("I:I").Find("*", After:=Range("I1")).Row
      
    Lastrow = Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
      
    PnrName = InputBox("Please Enter Last Name")

    Set Fltrrng = ActiveSheet.Range("$I$" & Firstrow & ":$I$" & Lastrow)

    Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Fltrrng, "=" & PnrName & "*")
    
    If Count > 0 Then
        Fltrrng.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="=" & PnrName & "*"
    Else
        MsgBox ("Last Name " & PnrName & " Does not Exist")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There are many more things that you need to take care of. **1.** When you are using `.Find("*"` to find the row then you have to be careful. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) **2.** For last row you can use `LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. This is also mentioned in that link

Comment: **3.**  You are using `InputBox`. What should happen when the user pressess cancel? You will need to handle that as well. **4.** You can skip the "=" in the `.CountIf` line so that it becomes `Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Fltrrng, PnrName & "*")`